# .NET IoC Unity Container Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I currently have a webapi which I am trying to implement Dependency Injection with. In my webapi I have a repository layer which communicates with the database and a service layer which simply stores all the business logic. The controllers are simply a request handler layer.

In the webapi architecture I have derived who made the request from the handlers (prior to reaching the controller layer). I would like to inject this into my repository using DI and IoC Unity. Is there a way I can do this. Perhaps factories using Unity Container.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm implementing it when I try to inject a `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` into a `Repository` class:

Global.asax

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Setup DI
        Bootstrapper.Initialise();

       // other init
    }
}
```

Bootstrapper.cs

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var connectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        var connectionFactoryConstructor = new InjectionConstructor(connectionFactory);

        container.RegisterType<ConfigManagement.Domain.Core.IParameterValueRepository, ConfigManagement.DAL.Core.ParameterValueRepository>(connectionFactoryConstructor);

        return container;
    }
}
```

My `Repository` implementation:

```
public class ParameterValueRepository : IParameterValueRepository
{
    private readonly OrmLiteConnectionFactory _dbFactory;

    public ParameterValueRepository(OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory)
    {
        _dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }
}
```

And finally my `Repository` interface:

```
public interface IParameterValueRepository
{
    List<ParameterValue> Get();
}
```